# those higher virtues of which, rendered without, one verily may sag

Tags: relative-clauses, late-modern-english

The following sentence is from *Lincoln in the Bardo*, an  experimental novel published in 2017. As an imitation of 19th-century English, is it crafted properly?

> I did always try, in all my aspects, to hew to elevation; to dispense
> therewith, into myself, those higher virtues **of which**, rendered **without**, one verily may sag, and, dwelling there in one’s misfortune, what avails.

I wonder if "those higher virtues of which, rendered without, one verily
may sag" should have been "those higher virtues, rendered without which one verily may sag."

Comment: It makes no sense to me! I had to look up _hew to_, which was unfamiliar to me as a British English speaker, but I still don't understand how the other phrases relate to one another.

Comment: @KateBunting - _Lincoln in the Bardo_ has been called 'experimental writing'. It has been said of George Saunders that he admires sentences that have “been the subject of so much concentration, they become a thing in the world.” The [New Yorker](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2017/02/13/george-saunders-gets-inside-lincolns-head), whose review is tellingly titled "George Saunders gets inside Lincoln's Head',  says that it contains much in the way of 'comic grandiloquence' (e.g. the quoted sentence). I would hesitate to recommend this book to any but the most advanced of non-native readers.

Comment: The author apparently got lost in his relative clause.

Comment: You may find a summary [here](https://www.litcharts.com/lit/lincoln-in-the-bardo/chapter-66) which I will not reproduce for copyright reasons.

Comment: I wrote "I would hesitate to recommend this book to any but the most advanced of non-native readers." I think many very advanced native readers would find this book tiring, annoying, or baffling, or all three.

Comment: Does your link suggest that quoted sentence is written in that way because the person who uttered it wasn't well educated?

Comment: It feels to me like a mixture of "Mulligan Stew" by Gilbert Sorrentino, and "The Sot-weed Factor" by John Barth.

Comment: @Apollyon - the quoted sentence is not mentioned in the review I linked to; the 'e.g.' is mine. Bearing in mind that the words quoted are the 'thoughts' if you like, of a ghost (I said it was experimental writing!) I would say that the quote has the feeling that the utterer is self-educated and very intelligent, and the lapses in the structure are deliberate.